# layer group in leaflet!

Tags: leaflet, group-layer

How to have different overlay layers in layer groups having different .geojson files? I want to show three different categories such as Toilets, dustbins and hospitals. There will be three different .geojson files. How can I have three categories at the right top of the map using leaflet.js?

Comment: Have you tried creating three instances of `L.GeoJson`, and creating a `L.Control.Layers` with all three of them?

Comment: RTFM. http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#control-layers-addoverlay